# axios fetches the old data(data before updating the document)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Below is my axios request where I am appending timestamp to the url. Am I doing it wrong? because I am getting the old data(the data before updating the document)

```
axios.get(`${url}?timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`)


router.get('/:uid', (req, res) => {User.findOne({ uid: req.params.uid})}
```

//editPost component

```
class EditUserDetails extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
render(){
        return(
            <div className="editUser"> 
                {console.log(this.props.currentUser)}
                <UserForm 
                    user={this.props.currentUser}
                    onSubmit={ (updates) => {
                        console.log(updates);

this.props.dispatch(editUser(this.props.currentUser.uid, updates));

this.props.history.push(`/user/${this.props.currentUser.uid}`);
                }} />
            </div>
        ) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should share a bigger part of your code. Maybe your update did not finish when you fetch data again.

Comment: @Gbacc added the component

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but like i told the other day, you are updating your user and switching directly to another component wich fetch the user data. But it doesnt wait for the update tu finish. Try puting logs before your axios update/get.